# Claims relating to be a prophet are unprovable?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/14291/according-to-skeptics-do-any-prophet-of-any-sort-existed

got closed. so no one has ever passed the skeptics test of being a prophet of one form or other?

PS: The million dollar challenge is the test to put the claimants through for their authenticity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question went through a number of iterations.

One version asked if any prophets existed, which was too broad: Firstly, it is one thing to argue whether David Koresh existed, and another to argue whether he spoke to God or not. Secondly, the only way to answer No (which would be the default skeptical position in the absence of extraordinary evidence) was to list every single prophet and explain why not.

Some versions offered some alternative answers that were about the limits of skepticism. You asked whether there was a basis of judging whether people spoke to supernatural beings. Questions about skepticism as a philosophy are off-topic here. This site is about applying skepticism to claims. (It is a subtle point, and one that confused many of us (including me) at first.)

You tried to argue that Skeptics can't prove/disprove the existence of god, which is largely unrelated, and ill-defined because the definition of god is not agreed upon.

The Million Dollar Challenge isn't a definitive answer. It provides a rhetorical device challenge people's beliefs in the supernatural that have an impact on the natural world. As their favourite psychic hasn't passed - nor even taken - the challenge, it makes them wonder why. However, someone failing to accept the challenge is not definitive proof that they have no powers - especially for putative prophets that preceded the Challenge.

In any case, there can be no Million Dollar Challenge for unfalsifiable claims, and most (not all) claims about gods and prophets are unfalsifiable.

(Which brings us back to the comment we disagreed over: Popper's concept of falsifiability is far more relevant than Goedel's concept of incompleteness.)

Answer (score 4):

Skeptics have been taking on claims of prophesy for years...  The Million Dollar Challenge is one such challenge.

The question itself wasn't closed because no one has ever refuted prophets, but because the question itself was poorly worded, as well as off topic.  If you could perhaps approach the question in a more non-adversarial way, as well as make A *specific* claim.

Comment: Off topic? Please tell me how to word it, I modified so many times and at the end instead of any guidance all I got was to close and move on, no one mentioned the million dollar challenge, I would have been happy with a refrence to that one.

Comment: @Arjang pick a specific claim, not just a generic "was there a prophet" but rather something like, "Were the predictions by Amn correct regarding the coming of a new consciousness".  Although, even then specific religions are better suited to religious stackexchanges as opposed to here, so make sure to keep it out of the religious philosophy and put it to a claim.

Comment: The whole thing started because I wrongly assumed the questions regarding people can be answerable, but it seems if people attach themselves to a supernatural being of some sort, then they can not be challenged/questioned without challenging/questioning the faith/belief issues that leads to no-where. I am happy with the million dollar challenge reference,

Answer (score 0):

Also, don't forget that one of the benefits of being a prophet is that you don't have to give specific predictions that are falsifiable why say something like:

> Starting January 2011 there be turmoil in Egypt which will ultimately
>   lead to a regime change.

When you can say:

> In the next five years, there will be troubles in a sandy place.

Or just push your time-line for predictions out so far that you will not care if they do not come to pass or not. Plus, part of the problem with prophecy in this day in age is that you can also argue that the event didn't happen because we were able to "alter the possible time-line" or you could use the many [worlds theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-worlds_interpretation) to argue that it happened, but just not to our time-line.

As such, ultimately I don't think that much in the way of attempting to predict the future is going be fully unprovable regardless of how skeptical you may be of it.